# What is the best way to run a django project on aws?

Tags: python, django, deployment, amazon-web-services

How should the project be deployed and run. There are loads of tools in this space. Which should be used and why?

- Supervisor
- Gunocorn
- Ngnix
- Fabric
- Boto
- Pip
- Virtualenv
- Load balancers

Comment: Off-topic, but you could consider using Heroku to deploy a Django project to AWS and skip most of this debate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on your configuration. We are using the following stack for our environment on Rackspace, but you can setup the same thing on AWS with EC2 instances.

- Ubuntu 11.04
- Varnish (in memory cache) to avoid disk seeks
- NginX to server static content
- Apache to server dynamic content (MOD-WSGI)
- Python 2.7.2 with Django
- Jenkins for our continuous builds
- GIT for version control
- Fabric for the deployment.

So the way it works is that a GIT push to the origin repository is being polled by Jenkins. Jenkins then pulls the changes down from the origin. Builds a Python Egg, runs Unit tests, uses Fabric to deploy this egg to the environments necessary and reloads the Apache config to make sure the forked Apache processes are picking up the new Python egg.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice stack Michael do you have your Nginx config in your project source code? What is managing the run of your python project and the number of threads. I believe Supervisor and  Gunocorn can help here.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the reason for using Apache+ModWSGI and Nginx rather than just Nginx fronting uWSGI? Also, for static content, why have ec2 units shifting it rather than just hosting on s3? Is there a performance impact?

Comment: Great point. We started out with Apache/ModWSGI, then added NginXinto the mix later, for predictability reasons we wanted to keep Apache in our PROD environments. S3 is awesome, totally. We got most of our stuff on Cloudfiles (the S3 equivalent). But there are static files that change extremely often for us and CloudFiles does not let you set a caching TTL on the CDN of < 20 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

As Michael Klockel already stated depends on your configuration, I have:

- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
- Nginx
- Uwsgi
- git version control
- python virtualenv and pip

You can check the deployment settings here:
[Django, Virtualenv, nginx + uwsgi import module wsgi error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163640/django-virtualenv-nginx-uwsgi-import-module-wsgi-error)

and why I use nginx and uwsgi here:
http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers

Also I use fabric for the deployment of the app, and chef solo http://ericholscher.com/blog/2010/nov/8/building-django-app-server-chef/

johny cache for sql queries and raven and sentry to keep a log of whats going on on the app.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [uWSGI+Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUwsgiModule) from a performance perspective (I think the comparison has already been linked in another answer), pip and [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for deployment as this keeps things self-contained, and facilitates clean deployment using fabric or similar. Use git for version control. [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) can handle continuous integration. I'd use the [AWS load balancer (ELB)](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) in front of your EC2 instances for balancing - does the job without you having to fret too much about it. [django-storages](http://code.larlet.fr/django-storages/) for uploading your static files to s3, that saves you the effort of having another server to hand out static files.

However, it depends a little on your admin overheads. If you're looking for something clean and simple for deployment and scaling, I'd scrap the whole AWS EC2 stack, use [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) as a front end, and s3 for your static files. This saves all the admin time of maintaining the boxes, and allows you to concentrate on the dev.